# Proof, that $\ln(1+x) > 2\sum_{k=0}^n\frac{1}{2k+1}\left(\frac{x}{2+x}\right)^{2k+1} $

Tags: sequences-and-series, taylor-expansion

Proof, that
$$ \ln(1+x) > 2\sum_{k=0}^n\frac{1}{2k+1}\left(\frac{x}{2+x}\right)^{2k+1} $$
for $$n = 0, 1, \ldots$$ and $$x>0$$.

I thought to derivate left ad right side
$$ \frac{1}{1+x} > (?) 2\sum_{k=0}^n\left(\frac{x}{2+x}\right)^{2k}\left(\frac{1}{2+x}\right)^{2} $$

And maybe than to make a geometric series
(maybe it's a bad idea)
I know that $$ 2\sum_{k=0}^n{x}^{2k} = \frac{2}{1-(x^2)}$$
But that one, that I have is more complicated...

Comment: An inequality does not necessarily still hold after differentiation.

Comment: @KStarGamer However you can integrate inequalities.

Comment: Let $y:=\frac{x}{2+x}$ so $1+x=\frac{1+y}{1-y}$. Prove the $n\to\infty$ limit is $\ln(1+x)$.

Answer (score 1):

Let $$f(x) = \frac x{x+2}$$ for $x\geq 0$.  Then $f(x) \in [0, 1)$, $f(x) > 0$ if $x>0$, and $$\begin{eqnarray}\frac 1{1+x} &=& \frac{2 f’(x)}{1-f(x)^2}\\
&=& 2f’(x) \sum_{k=0}^{\infty} f(x)^{2k}.
\end{eqnarray}$$

Now truncate the series and integrate.

Comment: How can I truncate the series?

Comment: @КатяПавліченко I mean: sum to a finite upper bound.